# EEVEE - make shadeless "image as plane" not effected by volumetrics and bloom like "grease pencil"

Tags: eevee-render-engine, image, grease-pencil, volumetrics, 2d

I'm making an environment that mixes 2D images and 3D objects. I want to give it a cartoon-ish look with uniform line art around each object. For the 2D images, I created the lineart in Photoshop, separated from the tree painting, so that the lineart is not affected by the lights by importing the image without shadows.

BUT (!) the tree lineart is still affected by bloom and volumetric fog...
I saw ways to get around with compositing but I'm still not comfortable with it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I get my way around this problem?

Comment: The tree lineart is not affected by bloom and fog I guess. For example, if you have a dense wall of fog and an object is behind it - then the fog is blocking the view on the object. That doesn't necessarily mean it affects the object directly. It affects the transmission of light in the air/space between the camera and the object. And bloom is an effect that "reacts" to the brightness of objects/pixels and is laid over the image. So the bloom doesn't affect the object, the object affects the bloom.

Comment: So what is it that you want, cut a hole in the fog to see the object behind it clearly for example? I guess then you will have to work with view layers, compositing like alpha over and maybe holdouts...

Comment: Okay so I didn't specify that I want to make the process as simple as possible because I'm making a short film where I will render a lot of images and different scenes with different places where the camera will probably move around, but I want to use the same process every time for 2D props in my scene. The goal is to have the same effect that grease pencil have, where nothing is interfering with the lines.

Comment: Bloom in Eevee is a screen space effect. It means it only knows about pixels that are rendered as a 2D array on your 2D screen. It doesn't see objects. I'm afraid that you'll have to render on separate view layers if you want to achieve what you're after.

Comment: I think the reason Line Art (and grease pencil) is not affected by the bloom effect is because the Line Art is overlaid on top of the screen AFTER the bloom is calculated and overlaid. It's IMO actually a limitation of Line Art and grease pencil, not a feature.

Comment: okay thanks for the help, I think I'm just going to make the lineart directly with grease pencil instead of going through photoshop.